# Given continuous $f$ and $g$, there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $\int_{a}^{c} f(x) \ \mathrm dx = \int_{c}^{b} g(x) \ \mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

If $f,g : [a,b] \to (0,\infty)$ are continuous functions, prove that there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that:
$$\int_{a}^{c} f(x) \ \mathrm dx = \int_{c}^{b} g(x) \ \mathrm dx$$

Comment: please add your thoughts and a descriptive title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $$h(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt-\int_x^bg(t)dt$$ and note that $h(a)=-\int_a^bg(t)dt\le0$ as $g$ is non negative, and $h(b)=\int_a^bf(t)dt\ge0$ as $f$ is non negative. Then apply intermediate value property for the continuous function $h$.